# Formatting and fill missed data based on column

Tags: awk, sed, text-formatting

I have the data in this format and I want to sort it based on the label in each column. Would want to replace the missing field by a comma (`,`) like shown below

```
2018-03-13 02:09:12,AB=123,BC=6,CAB=Jax,XYZ=Xax
2018-03-13 02:09:13,AB=234,BC=6,CAB=Jax,XYZ=Ram
2018-03-13 02:11:03,AB=567,BC=6,XYZ=Xulu
```

Expected results.

```
2018-03-13 02:09:12,    AB=123, BC=6,   CAB=Jax,    XYZ=Xax
2018-03-13 02:09:13,    AB=234, BC=6,   CAB=Jax,    XYZ=Ram
2018-03-13 02:11:03,    AB=567, BC=6,          ,    XYZ=Xulu
```

Comment: @αғsнιη - Did you get a chance to check this for me.

Comment: How do we know which field names are the ones to match? (e.g. if your third line was first, we wouldn't know about `CAB` until too late)

Comment: @αғsнιη - can we discuss on this please?

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN { OFS = FS = "," }

FNR==1 {
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {
        split($i, a, "=")
        f[i] = a[1]
    }
}

{
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {
        split($i, a, "=")
        if (a[1] != f[i]) {
            for (j = NF + 1; j > i; --j)
                $j = $(j - 1)
            $i = ""
        }

        $i = sprintf("%10s", $i)
    }

    print
}
```

This `awk` program assumes that the first line of the input file is *correct* in that it contains all the fields in the correct positions.

In the text below, "all fields" and "the fields" refers to all but the first field, which is left untouched.

For the first line only, it reads the bits before the `=` in the fields and stores that in the `f` array for the corresponding field position.

For all lines, it does the same sort of splitting of the fields' contents on `=` and compares the bit before the `=` with what the `f` array says it's supposed to be.  If there's a mismatch, the fields from that point on are "shifted right" one position and the current field is emptied.

Then all fields are reformatted as a right-justified string of 10 characters, and the whole modified record (line) is printed.

Running this on the example data:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
2018-03-13 02:09:12,    AB=123,      BC=6,   CAB=Jax,   XYZ=Xax
2018-03-13 02:09:13,    AB=234,      BC=6,   CAB=Jax,   XYZ=Ram
2018-03-13 02:11:03,    AB=567,      BC=6,          ,  XYZ=Xulu
```